# iOS and parse.com integration logic

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am creating an app for iOS using **Parse** as backend. Users can add posts by selecting any of the three following types: public, theme (a,b,c,d,e), friend. When other users login he can read public and theme posts on his profile screen and friend posts can be read on his private screen. Each user can see other user profiles.

What should I do? Should I create one single table to handle all the above or create table for each user in Parse.com. But If i create a table for each user like `username_ns` than problem is how many table I can create in Parse.com. does it proper solution?

Can you give me proper suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely **not** create a separate table for each user. Here's what I suggest:

Use the built-in `User` table, then create a `Post` table. Then take advantage of Parse's Access Control List (ACL) functionality to give certain users access to certain posts.

Take a look at the sample project AnyPic to see how user registration and and object-level security works: https://parse.com/tutorials

Good luck. :)